# Normal estimates curvature field coming back NAN

Tags: c++, normals, point-clouds, point-cloud-library

I am computing the surface normals for an organized point cloud as follows:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud = create_point_cloud_ptr(cap_depth, cap_rgb);

// estimate normals
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>::Ptr normals (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>);

pcl::IntegralImageNormalEstimation<pcl::PointXYZRGB, pcl::Normal> ne;
ne.setNormalEstimationMethod (ne.AVERAGE_3D_GRADIENT);
ne.setMaxDepthChangeFactor(15);
ne.setNormalSmoothingSize(10.0f);
ne.setInputCloud(cloud);
ne.compute(*normals);
```

When I iterate through the normals, the curvature field is set to NAN for all points. Am I doing something wrong in the calculation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the `AVERAGE_3D_GRADIENT` method does not compute surface curvature, need to use `ne.COVARIANCE_MATRIX`